# Object "c" not found

Tags: r, function

I am having a problem with the "Object not found" error and  I can't seem to find the solution.

I am using several functions to put data into a certain format and the code looks something like this:

```
convert <- function (t,m,p){
if(d == "N") {
t <- f1 (f = f1, s = s1, m=m1, d="N") #this runs without a problem
c <- f2 (t = t, d ="N") #and this is where I get the issue
}
```

The `f2` function looks like this:

```
f2 <- function (t, m, p, d) {
if (d == "N"){
c <- unique (t[,c("d","k1","k2")])
c$l <- NA
c$b <- NA
}
```

And then I get the error:

```
Error in f2(t=t, d="N"):
object "c" not found
```

Comment: `if (d = "N")` needs two `==`. And `c` is the name of a function, choose another name, say, `x` and retry.

Comment: Hey Rui, my bad, that `=` was a typo and changing the name of `c`d id not help unfortunately.

Comment: `c$l` / `c$b` will not work as you are using the `c` function  while creating a variable `c`. can you show us the updated code as per @Rui Barradas comment?

Comment: I tried changin the name of it but I still get the same error, I think it has to do with the way I call function `f2`in the first box of code. But I can not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @RuiBarradas when I run the lines individually first it ends up working, but when I just run the function I get the same error...